# Is there any way to extract "method" and "params" of unchecked extrinsic using ScaleCode/TypeInfo traits?

Tags: extrinsic, wasm, scale-codec

I'm wondering if there is any way to extract information about method and parameter of Extrinsic(Unchecked/CheckedExtrinsic) using  TypeInfo and Scale codec.

In `polkadotJs` there is `toString` method on tx that can be used to represent extrinsic as a JSON and fetch info about method/params.

```json
{"signature":{"signer":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","signature":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","era":{"immortalEra":"0x00"},"nonce":0,"tip":0},"method":{"callIndex":"0x0307","args":{"dest":"0xf24FF3a9CF04c71Dbc94D0b566f7A27B94566cac","value":100000}}}
```

Essentially I would like to fetch same info at the rust side (in runtime).

One way to do it is would be to implement new trait for `RuntimeCall` that would return

```rust
pub trait GetMethodName{
fn (&self) -> String;
}
```

And implementing it in `Runtime`, so something like

```
impl MethodName for RuntimeCall {
    fn into(self) -> CallType {
        match self {
            RuntimeCall::FooPallet(pallet_foo::Call::foo {}) => "foo".to_string(),
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm pretty sure there should be a way to utilize Scale codec and `TypeInfo`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the context in which you want this information, but if you're just keen to connect to a node/chain, download blocks and decode extrinsics, then have a look at [Subxt](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt), which is a Rust library for interacting with nodes/chains.

This example inparticular downloads blocks and prints a bunch of information about them:

https://docs.rs/subxt/latest/subxt/book/usage/blocks/index.html#example

If you just want to understand which calls (and more) are available on a node, then the Subxt CLI tool has a nice `explore` command which can be pointed at a node and give information about it (`cargo install subxt-cli`). We have also been working on a UI to explore this information here: https://paritytech.github.io/subxt-explorer/

Internally, this all relies on obtaining the metadata from a node (the Subxt CLI command has a `metadata` option to download this for you), and then decoding it (the SCALE encoded metadata can be decoded via `parity-scale-codec` to [this](https://github.com/paritytech/frame-metadata/blob/a07b2451b82809501fd797691046c1164f7e8840/frame-metadata/src/lib.rs#L85)).

The metadata contains `TypeInfo` for all relevant types, as well as information on things like which calls are available in each pallet. Calls are basically represented as a `Variant` type, where the variant names are the call names and the variant fields are the arguments to the call (see [the scale-info docs](https://docs.rs/scale-info/latest/scale_info/enum.TypeDef.html) for more on what the type info contains).

Comment: Hi, thanks for a quick response, but what i need is to get name of the extrinsic and its params in a generic way in node runtime not outside of the node ;/

Answer (score 0):

*I got an answer on github so copying it here for the record*

Types annotated with `#[derive(TypeInfo)]` end up with a `MyType::type_info()` [method](https://docs.rs/scale-info/latest/scale_info/trait.TypeInfo.html). Look through the [docs](https://docs.rs/scale-info/latest/scale_info/enum.TypeDef.html) there and you'll see how to obtain various information about the type.

You can't get any information about values though; the macro doesn't know anything about the values of a particular instance. All you get is the type information which is tied to how some instance of that type would be SCALE encoded via parity-scale-codec.

If you have some SCALE encoded bytes already, and you have a `scale_info::PortableRegistry` describing the shape of those bytes (this can be constructed from some TypeInfos), then libraries like [scale-decode](https://github.com/paritytech/scale-decode) can be used to decode those bytes into some type (anything implementing `DecodeAsType` which has a compatible shape), and building on that, [scale-value](https://github.com/paritytech/scale-value) offers a Value type which is one such target that any SCALE encoded bytes can decode into, and can then be iterated over or whatever to explore the value.